# How to make a Material UI layout

Tags: material-ui

For vuetify, I use `<v-content>` for making may layout when I'm using Vue. Since I got used to this, I was finding this kind of component on Material UI.

Is there a way to convert this layout from Vuetify to Material UI?

```
<v-app>
  <v-toolbar app>...</v-toolbar>
  <v-navigation-drawer app>...</v-navigation-drawer permanent>
  <v-content><nuxt/></v-content>
</app>
```

I was using nuxt on Vuetify. Now I'm using next for my react project.
I'm kind of finding the `<v-app>` and `<v-content>` like component for Material UI but I can't seem to find it. Or do I make that layout myself?

Answer (score 0):

well, while Vue is more of a framework in the classic acceptance of the notion, react is more of a library, providing components that you can assemble in any way you may find appropriate

so you'll have to build that layout yourself

have a look at this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/j1n94qvmvw